# Получение access_token vk api

Tags: vkontakte-api, golang, вконтакте

Как мне перенаправить Code на ссылку получения access_token как в этой инструкции ?

> Получение code
>
> После успешной авторизации приложения браузер пользователя будет
> перенаправлен по адресу redirect_uri, указанному при открытии диалога
> авторизации. При этом код для получения ключа доступа code будет
> передан как GET-параметр:
>
> REDIRECT_URI?code=7a6fa4dff77a228eeda56603b8f53806c883f011c40b72630bb50df056f6479e52a
>
> Параметр code может быть использован в течение 1 часа для получения
> ключа доступа к API access_token с вашего сервера.
>
> В случае возникновения ошибки браузер пользователя будет перенаправлен
> с кодом и описанием ошибки:
>
> REDIRECT_URI?error=invalid_request&error_description=Invalid+display+parameter
>
> Получение access_token
>
> Для получения access_token необходимо выполнить запрос с вашего
> сервера на https://oauth.vk.com/access_token, передав следующие
> параметры:
>
> • client_id (обязательный) — идентификатор вашего приложения.
>
> • client_secret (обязательный) — защищенный ключ вашего приложения
> (указан в настройках приложения).
>
> • redirect_uri (обязательный) — URL, который использовался при
> получении code на первом этапе авторизации. Должен быть аналогичен
> переданному при авторизации.
>
> • code (обязательный) — временный код, полученный после прохождения
> авторизации.
>
> Пример запроса:
>
> https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=1&client_secret=H2Pk8htyFD8024mZaPHm&redirect_uri=http://mysite.ru&code=7a6fa4dff77a228eeda56603b8f53806c883f011c40b72630bb50df056f6479e52a

Comment: Что значит перенаправить Code?

Answer (score 0):

`https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=АЙДИ_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ&display=mobile&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=offline&response_type=token&v=5.126&state=123456`

В scope перечисляешь параметры, которым нужен доступ. Например: photos,status,wall.
Параметр offline нужен для того, чтоб токен был вечный и не пришлось снова авторизовываться.

После перехода по этой ссылке, открывается страница авторизации, где пользователь авторизуется. После авторизации, получаем конечную ссылку(она поменяется) и там будет access_token. Останется только вытащить ту часть ссылки